# Detecting Mouse over JPanel Child

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, mouselistener

I have used `MouseAdapter` in order to detect if the mouse enters or exits a JPanel and it works, *somewhat*, because it doesn't detect if the mouse is hovering over the JPanel.

```
public class SearchResultPanel extends JPanel{

  private class mousePanelListener extends MouseAdapter{ 
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        setHighlightBorder(); //"highlight" the panel
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        setDefaultBorder(); //"unhighlight" the panel
    }
  }
  private final Border highlightBorder;
  private final Border defaultBorder;

  //ctor
  SearchResultPanel(String data){
        super();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(data);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        add(textArea);

        addMouseListener(new mouseMotionPanelListener());
        setFocusable(true);

        highlightBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 5);
        defaultBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
  }


   private void setHighlightBorder(){
    setBorder(highlightBorder);
   }

   private void setDefaultBorder(){
    setBorder(defaultBorder);
   }
}
```

The `SearchResultPanel`s highlight only when the mouse is at the edge(outline) of the panel. They go back to the default border if they are inside the panel or outside. 
How can I detect if the mouse is over the JPanel so the JPanel sets its highlighted border?

Comment: Where's the highlightBorder method?

Comment: updated the code with the setBorders

Comment: Have you added anything to SearchResultPanel that has a MouseListener attached to it?

Comment: The SearchResultPanels Highlight only when the mouse is at the edge(outline) of the panel. They go back to the default border if they are inside the panel or outside

Comment: There is only a textfield inside these panels

Comment: Given you're using a GridLayout, it's possible that the textfields might be consume the mouse events. Try a test withi nothing in the SearchResultPane

Comment: You are correct. The JTextFields were consuming the mouse events

Comment: You could 1- add an small empty border to panel, which will allow you to trap MouseEnter events, but the text fields will cause a MouseExit event. 2- You could add MouseListeners to the text field, using a counter you could detect when the mouse has exited the fields a well. 3- You could register an AWTEventListener with the Toolkit so that you can get hold of the global event queue and detect the mouse enter exit events and determine if the component is the panel or parent of the component....

Comment: Easiest way would be to MouseListener the JTextArea, personally. Might have to get the Area's parent component (the custom JPanel, by casting) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `addMouseMotionListener` method instead.

Comment: MouseEntered comes from MouseListener